# Error while Running ionic 3 on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I developed an ionic 3 application on the windows operating system (Windows 8) build the app for android and everything work fine.
Then I need to build for iOS , so I copied the project to MacBook to build for IOS.

I have run the latest npm but when I run

```
ionic Cordova emulate ios --target="iPhone-X"
```

it load the simulator but then displays the error below

```
An error was encountered processing the command     (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
 Failed to install the requested application
 An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
 Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
 logPath:          /Users/lekan/desktop/testProject/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

What are my doing wrong

Below is my ionic info
    ionic info

Result

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.2

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.5.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

Node  : v6.11.4
npm   : 3.10.10 
OS    : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004 

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

backend : pro
```

Comment: Can you show `ionic info`?

Comment: @Sampath , I have updated the question with my ionic info result

Comment: `ionic serve` works on MAC?

Comment: Yes. Ionic serve runs

Comment: Any luck on this? @devloper2009

Comment: Not yet @cdh429

Answer (score 1):

I cant find the error for
 **ionic Cordova emulate ios**

but if you go there 
 **platforms/ios/cordova**  and click on  **run**  file the simulator work perfectly